# How can I create a public static method while implementing an interface in c#?

Tags: c#

I have the following interface

```
public interface IQueryBuilder
{
    SqlCommand Build(IReportDataSource dataSource, List<IReportColumn> columns, List<IReportRelationMapping> relationMappings, IReportFilterMapping filters, List<IReportColumn> columsToSortBy, ReportFormat reportFormat);

    string GetSqlClause(List<IReportFilter> reportFilters, ref List<IDataParameter> sqlParams);
}
```

However, I would like to be able to access the method `GetSqlClause` in the implementation directly.

Here is how I implemented the above

```
public class QueryBuilder : IQueryBuilder
{
    public SqlCommand Build(IReportDataSource dataSource, List<IReportColumn> columns, List<IReportRelationMapping> relationMappings, IReportFilterMapping filters, List<IReportColumn> columsToSortBy, ReportFormat reportType)
    {
        //Do something awsome!!!
        string sqlQuery = "";

        List<IDataParameter> sqlParameters = new List<IDataParameter>();

        return this.GetSqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlParameters);
    }

    private SqlCommand GetSqlCommand(string sqlQuery, List<IDataParameter> sqlParams)
    {
        var command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery);

        foreach (IDataParameter dataParameter in sqlParams)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(dataParameter);
        }

        return command;
    }


    public static string GetSqlClause(List<IReportFilter> reportFilters, ref List<IDataParameter> sqlParams)
    {
        string sqlFilter = "";

        if (reportFilters != null && reportFilters.Any())
        {
            //At this point we know there are some filter to add to the list

            var firstFilter = reportFilters.First();

            foreach (var reportFilter in reportFilters)
            {

                var parameter = GenerateDbParameter("p" + sqlParams.Count, reportFilter.FormattedValue, SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                ....
                ....
            }
        }

        return sqlFilter;
    }

    private static IDataParameter GenerateDbParameter(string parameterName, object parameterValue, SqlDbType parameterType)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameterName) || parameterValue == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        var parameter = new SqlParameter("@" + parameterName, parameterType)
        {
            Value = parameterValue
        };

        return parameter;
    }


}
```

Because I am using `static` on my `GetSqlClause` method I get an error

> cannot implement an interface member because it is static.

What is a good work around to this problem? How can I access my `GetSqlClause` directly?

Comment: Is there a reason you want it to be static?  Does it need to be?  Just don't make it static.

Comment: having `static` members in an `interface` doesn't make sense.  Why can't you use `QueryBuilder.GetSqlClause` instead of `IQueryBuilder.GetSqlClause`

Comment: Side note: Passing `System.List<IDataParameter>` as `ref` parameter is a poor design. Pass it regularly, or even better, as `IList<IDataParameter>`.

Comment: @Jaylen, I used to wonder this to.  My problem was that I didn't understand the point of interfaces.  You should read up on Test-Driven Design and Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your method to be static *and* implement an interface, the language won't let you do that, but you can work around it in several ways:

- If accessing the whole implementation from a static context makes sense, you can simply declare a singleton object:

  ```
  public static QueryBuilder Instance { get; } = new QueryBuilder();
  ```

  And now you have access to the `QueryBuilder.Instance` static property, whose value implements `IQueryBuilder`.
- Through an *explicit method implementation*. This is an additional instance method which implements the interface method, and whose signature won't conflict with another method in the class.

  ```
  string IQueryBuilder.GetSqlClause(List<IReportFilter> reportFilters, ref List<IDataParameter> sqlParams)
  {
      // Call the static method, this is *not* a recursive call
      return GetSqlClause(reportFilters, ref sqlParams);
  }
  ```

  The general syntax of an explicit implementation is:

  ```
  ReturnType InterfaceName.MethodName(ParamType param)
  {
      ...
  }
  ```
- Another (simpler) solution would be to use two distinct method names.

Comment: That's still an instance method; it's not static.

Comment: @Servy yes, the instance method calls the static one. This answers the question the way I understood it.

Comment: @Servy I rewrote the answer to hopefully make my point more clear, it it better now? Even though the design may be questionable, it could potentially prove useful in some circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

C# doesn't support static members implementing interface methods.

Comment: That is correct, but StackOverflow is not a trivia game.  Static members in an interface don't even make sense, but from your answer, the OP might assume that it's merely not supported